# Scala way to change this into a list?

Tags: scala

Assume I have a routine which takes an enumeration value as an argument and returns a Boolean ... and I want to check a set of those enumeration values to see if they are all true.  Is there a idiomatic way to do it.  This was my "old school" attempt which seems non-scala-ish:

```
def allUnitQueuesEmpty(): Boolean =
    ( getQueue(QID.CPU).isEmpty() &&
      getQueue(QID.L1C_I).isEmpty() &&
      getQueue(QID.L1D_I).isEmpty() &&
      getQueue(QID.L1VC_I).isEmpty() &&
      getQueue(QID.L1C_D).isEmpty() &&
      getQueue(QID.L1D_D).isEmpty() &&
      getQueue(QID.L1VC_D).isEmpty() &&
      getQueue(QID.L1WB_D).isEmpty() &&
      getQueue(QID.L2C).isEmpty() &&
      getQueue(QID.L2WB).isEmpty() &&
      getQueue(QID.MEM_RD).isEmpty() &&
      getQueue(QID.MEM_WRT).isEmpty() );
```

Can this be done with a List?

-Jay

Answer (score 22):

No need for a list, actually. `QID.values()` returns an array of all `QID` values, and an array can be implicitly converted to a Scala collection, which allows you to define

```
def allUnitQueuesEmpty(): Boolean = QID.values.forall(v => getQueue(v).isEmpty)
```

If you only needed some of those values, this would work instead:

```
import QID._
def l1UnitQueuesEmpty(): Boolean = Array(L1C_I, L1D_I, L1VC_I).forall(v => getQueue(v).isEmpty)
```

Answer (score 5):

All of Scala's collections have `forall` and `exists` methods which ascertain whether the collection to which they're applied satisfies the predicate supplied as an argument (over the elements of the collection) for every element (`forall`) or for at least one element (`exists`).